# Multi-Column Primary Key or Unique Constraint?

Tags: sql, indexing, primary-key

I have a `Country` table which includes the columns `ID`, `Name` and `Code`. All three of these columns should contain unique values and cannot be `NULL`.

My question is, would I be better to create a primary key on the `ID` column and a unique constraint for the `Name` and `Code` columns (in one index, I guess), or would it be better to just include the `Name` and `Code` columns in the primary key with the `ID`? And why? Are there potential downsides or complexities that will result from having a multiple-column primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all - yes, a compound primary key made up of three columns makes it more annoying to join to this table - any other table wanting to join to the `Country` table will **also** have to have **all three columns** to establish the join.

And more importantly - it's **NOT** the same restriction!

If you have the PK on `ID` and a unique constraint on both `Code` and `Name` separately, then this is **NOT** valid:

```
ID    Code     Name
--------------------------
41    CH       Switzerland
341   CH       Liechtenstein
555   LIE      Liechtenstein
```

because the `Code` of `CH` and the `Name` of `Liechtenstein` both appear twice.

But if you have a single PK on all three columns together - then this is **valid** because each row has a different **tuple** of data - (`41`, `CH`, `Switzerland`) is **not** the same as (`341`, `CH`, `Liechtenstein`) and therefore, those two rows are admissible.

If you put the PK on all three columns at once, then the **uniqueness** only extends to the **whole tuple** (all three columns) - each column separately **can have** "duplicates".

So it really boils down to

- what you really need (which uniqueness)
- how easy you want to make it to join to this table

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. I'm aware of the difference between the two constraints, but I guess the compound PK would allow both ('41, CH, Switzerland') and ('555, CH, Switzerland'), which is clearly undesirable.  In any case, the extra difficulty in joining this table makes the decision easy for me.

Comment: Really great answer, marc. One style suggestion: you might consider using *emphasis* instead of **bold**.